# My kendo Grid column is extending the table without wrapping or overflowing the value

Tags: css, kendo-grid, overflow, kendo-asp.net-mvc, word-wrap

The value column in the grid is extending the table. I have tried adding styles but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)

.Name("grid_profiles")
.Selectable()
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.IsSelected).Title("Is Selected").Width("50px").ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align : center;'><input type='checkbox' #= IsSelected ? 'checked=checked' : '' # disabled='disabled' /></div>");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Title("Data Element").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Desc).Title("Description").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "word-wrap:break-word;" }).Width("300px");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Format).Title("Format").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Value).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
    columns.Bound(p => p.Type).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(p => p.DataType).Hidden();
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Sort(sort =>
    {
        sort.Add("IsSelected").Descending();
    })
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.Id);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller"))
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify an explicit width for that column? You have specified explicit width for other columns... Is there a reason you can't use that same approach for the Value column of your grid?

Like so:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Value)
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" })
    .Width(200); // Like this
```

Comment: I tried specifying the width of the column. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you're getting after applying the width to your column? :)